# clicking a button second time, getting different result

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

When a button (material ui) is clicked for a second time, I want that button to be disabled (`disabled={true}`). I did not find any example related to this on StackOverflow.

```js
<Button
  onClick={this.startDraw.bind(this)}
  disabled={}
  startIcon={<Brush />}
>
```

At first, the button is clickable. When it is clicked, something happens, but when this same button is clicked a second time, the button should be disabled (cannot be clicked anymore).

Comment: try to create a counter state for this button, when the state becomes 2 disable it.
disabled={counterState == 2}

Comment: @WaleedJubeh could you provide working example ?

Comment: https://replit.com/join/kdwzrqpsuh-waleedjubeh

Answer (score 0):

For Class component use

```
    state = {
    count: 0
    };
this.setState({ count: count + 1 }); // use this on your button click
```

and for the button part

```
   <Button
    onClick={this.startDraw.bind(this)}
    disabled={state.count == 2}
    startIcon={<Brush />}
  />
```

for functional component use this approach

```
   const [count , setCount ] = useState(0);
   setCount(count + 1) // use this on your button call

    <Button
    onClick={this.startDraw.bind(this)}
    disabled={count == 2}
    startIcon={<Brush />}
/>
```

Comment: it says count is not defined at here '        count: count + 1
' error is on that second count

Comment: are u using class component or functional component?

Comment: This will disable it on the third click. You need to change it to disabled={count === 1}